# Changing cell formatting based on data in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sales spreadsheet. I'm trying to change the formatting of cells based on the values in other cells.

Values are monthly sales targets and beneath them are actuals. I need the actuals cells to change color based on whether they have reached/exceeded the target or failed to meet the target. Each actual cell is to be compared against the cell above it (target row).

My code will work for one row but not when I add multiple rows i.e. more than one Range.

Sample worksheet with data
[image: 1]

```vb
Sub FormattingNumValue()

Dim i As Range
For Each i In Range("A3:L3")
    If IsEmpty(i.Value) = False Then
        If (i.Value < i.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
            i.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        Else
            i.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
        End If
    Else
        i.ClearFormats
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Check if cell was changed and call Update function/procedure
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:L3")) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, Range("A9:L9")) Is Nothing Then
        'MsgBox "Something changed"
       Call FormattingNumValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Is it possible to check multiple rows using the one function? I tried a collection but it throws an out of range error.

Comment: why don't you use conditional formatting?

Comment: To build on Ike's point, which should be the case as you have a contiguous range being affected, you would have two (2) conditional formats, one for each color.  `=A3<A4` is Color 1, `=A3>=A4` is Color 2.

Answer (score 0):

Example of the conditional formatting:

```
`Color 1
=A3<A4

'Color 2
=A3>=A4
```

[image]

[image]

---

Edit1:

Programmatically applying conditional formatting:

```
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    With Range(Cells(desiredRow,firstColumn), Cells(desiredRow, lastColumn))
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A3>A4"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        End With
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A3<=A4"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that I've tried conditional formatting but the original sheet has formulae that is copied across other to other cells and copying throws the formatting as it copies the formatting rule irrespective of whether a lock is on the cell or not. This was why I chose the VBA route.

Comment: @KEC-IT: are you aware that you can set conditional formatting using VBA?

Comment: @KEC-IT See `Edit1`

Comment: @Cyril many thanks for expanding your answer, I'll apply that code to my sheet and I'll respond when I get to test it out.